# Is is possible to write content in next page and jump back to previous page in PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

I am trying to write some content in pdf using Apache PDFBox. I have to create a table and write some content into every column.

Let's say my table has 5 columns and I am writing content into the second column and content exceeds the length of the page. I closed the previous contentstream and created new contentstream, adding a new page to contentstream. But for the next column, I have to jump back to the previous page.

How would I do that? Can anyone help with this?

Comment: *"I closed the prevoius contentstream and created new contentstream,adding new page to contentstream."* - If you want to jump back and forth between pages that approach probably is not appropriate. Have you considered keeping both pages open to freely go back and forth as long as you draw the table? If you need to close the current content stream before opening the next one, though, you can add multiple streams to a single page, use `AppendMode.APPEND`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide me with any specific content about AppendMode.APPEND in pdfBox. I was searching for it But didn't find any blog or content. @mkl Can you give an example of adding multiple streams to a single page? It will be easy to understand if it is according to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I closed the previous contentstream and created new contentstream, adding a new page to contentstream.

If you want to jump back and forth between pages, that approach probably is not appropriate. Have you considered keeping both pages open to freely go back and forth as long as you draw the table?

If you really need to close the current content stream before opening the next one, though, you can add multiple streams to a single page, use `AppendMode.APPEND`.

In a comment you continued asking:

> Can you give an example of adding multiple streams to a single page? It will be easy to understand if it is according to my question.

This is a simple example for going back and forth between two pages and adding content in a new content stream each time:

```java
try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
    PDRectangle mediaBox = PDRectangle.LETTER;
    document.addPage(new PDPage(mediaBox));
    document.addPage(new PDPage(mediaBox));

    PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    for (int column = 1; column < 6; column++) {
        try (PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(document, document.getPage(0), AppendMode.APPEND, true)) {
            canvas.beginText();
            canvas.setFont(font, 12);
            canvas.newLineAtOffset(column * (mediaBox.getWidth() / 7), mediaBox.getHeight() / 7);
            canvas.showText("Column " + column + " A");
            canvas.endText();
        }
        try (PDPageContentStream canvas = new PDPageContentStream(document, document.getPage(1), AppendMode.APPEND, true)) {
            canvas.beginText();
            canvas.setFont(font, 12);
            canvas.newLineAtOffset(column * (mediaBox.getWidth() / 7), 6 * mediaBox.getHeight() / 7);
            canvas.showText("Column " + column + " B");
            canvas.endText();
        }
    }
    document.save(new File("BackAndForthBetweenPages.pdf"));
}
```

*([BackAndForthBetweenPages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/BackAndForthBetweenPages.java#L36) test `testForSagarKumar`)*

Here we add content to the first two pages of a document in 5 columns, column-by-column.

The result:

[image: screen shot]